# The command 'find' inside awk does not work

Tags: awk

Looking for hidden files:

```
$ find . -type f -not -name "."

./.kjj.jpg
./2.jpg.~1~
```

Now, using the same commands, but inside awk:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{ system(find . -type f -not -name ".") }'

awk: 1: unexpected character '.'
```

Why does it not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{ system("find . -type f -not -name \".\"") }'
```

The `system()` function accepts a string; `find . -type...` withut quotes is simply invalid AWK syntax.

Comment: I had the same problem and it seems it would help me. I have asked question here:https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/446253/awk-script-to-list-files-with-specified-filenames/446405?noredirect=1#comment809488_446405. but now my problem is that how can I pass the directory as a variable to find command?? can you help me with that?